# Pandas - set datetime / Timestamp value with apply

Tags: python, pandas

Lets consider the following dataframe:

```
a=pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(10)))
```

Trying to create a new column from it with apply:
The column is supposed to contain Timestamp object

```
def test(x):
    x["date"]=pd.Timestamp("2017-01-01")
    return x

a.apply(test,axis=1)
```

However this result in a dataframe containing the `.value` numerical attribute of the timestamp:

```
    0   date
0   0   1483228800000000000
1   1   1483228800000000000
2   2   1483228800000000000
3   3   1483228800000000000
4   4   1483228800000000000
5   5   1483228800000000000
6   6   1483228800000000000
7   7   1483228800000000000
8   8   1483228800000000000
9   9   1483228800000000000
```

How come it is so? How can I get the correct Timestamp in the DataFrame?

---

Edit: here the full code that is giving me problem:
This is for respondant to understand that i am not trying to set a simply formed list of datetimes to a new column:

```
def mae(x):
    entry=x.name[0]
    exit=x.name[1]
    m=d.loc[entry:exit,"close"]
    if x.dir==-1:
        r=(m.sub(m[::-1].cummax()[::-1])).abs().max()
        imax=(m.sub(m[::-1].cummax()[::-1])).idxmin()
    elif x.dir==1:
        r=(m.sub(m[::-1].cummin()[::-1])).abs().max()
        imax=(m.sub(m[::-1].cummin()[::-1])).idxmax()   
    else: r=0
    x['mae']=r*gbp['multiplier']
    x['peak']=imax 
    return x

k=g.head().apply(mae,axis=1)
```

This takes as input another dataframe and some financial prices data stored in a database - so a bit difficult to invent an example that at the same time is simple enough for people to grab it quickly and complicated enough as to justify the use of `.apply`.

I think there is something i dont understand / or a bug in the `.apply` function - this is what i would like to have input and help on. Thanks guys!

Comment: `df['date']=pd.Timestamp("2017-01-01")`

Comment: @Wen This is a simplified example of a more complicated code where this problem arise. Please provide an answer in the context of using `.apply` (if you wish to provide an answer). Thx!

Comment: have you looked at [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)?

Comment: @MattR yes I def did. Same result

Comment: what is your desired outcome? you're just making a more complicated way of setting an entire column to a certain value. I know you said this is just a simplified version - but this may be *too* simplified. Or is your actual data just integers?

Comment: @MattR I just edited the question with the real piece of code containing the `.apply` function and the datetime. This is really just to show that the problem cannot be resolved by removing `.apply`. Hopefully the conversation can remain on the more simple example code and the problem in the `.apply` function. Thx!

Comment: a quick question though, does your simplified example still hold valid to solve your real problem (if we provide an answer to it)?

Comment: @stucash The answer need to be using the `.apply` method. I know I can convert back the int to a timestamp the line after apply. I am just seeking a cleaner way of doing it / or at least to understand what is the fault in the original example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a few rounds of debugging with your code and further into pandas, it seems there was something you can improve in your code.

you can read more details in [_setitem_with_indexer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/indexing.py), line 387-393
and in [numpy.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

In short, `_setitem_with_indexer` makes use of `numpy.concatenate` as part of setting new values using indexer.

Because your first column in `a` had only integers and your new column `a['date']` was trying to concatenate an `integer`, with a `pandas.Timestamp`(it's actually a `numpy.datetime64`),
numpy simply refused to do that.

to show that this is the case, we can illustrate by following examples.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s1 = [1]

s2 = np.array([np.datetime64("2017-01-01")])

s3 = [pd.Timestamp("2017-01-01")]

a = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range("01-01-2017", "01-06-2017"))

b = pd.DataFrame(data=["d", "c", "d", "d"])

c = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(10))) 

def test(x):
    x["date"]=pd.Timestamp("2017-01-01")
    return x
```

**Trials**

```
a.apply(test, axis=1)

# output 

           0       date
0 2017-01-01 2017-01-01
1 2017-01-02 2017-01-01
2 2017-01-03 2017-01-01
3 2017-01-04 2017-01-01
4 2017-01-05 2017-01-01
5 2017-01-06 2017-01-01

b.apply(test, axis=1)

# output

   0                 date
0  d  1483228800000000000
1  c  1483228800000000000
2  d  1483228800000000000
3  d  1483228800000000000

c.apply(test,axis=1)

# output

   0                 date
0  0  1483228800000000000
1  1  1483228800000000000
2  2  1483228800000000000
3  3  1483228800000000000
4  4  1483228800000000000
5  5  1483228800000000000
6  6  1483228800000000000
7  7  1483228800000000000
8  8  1483228800000000000
9  9  1483228800000000000
```

I think this is more behaviour of `numpy.concatenate`. if we choose to 
use pd.Timestamp we will observe different behaviour, which essentially would succeed in concatenation; but not the same with numpy.datetime64, which is what's used inside `_setitem_with_indexer`.

**Observation**

```
np.concatenate([s1,s2])

# output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: invalid type promotion
invalid type promotion

np.concatenate([s1,s3])

# output

array([1, Timestamp('2017-01-01 00:00:00')], dtype=object)
***please note here dtype is object***
```

As for cleanness or elegance, I think Wen's comment is already very minimal, but you might have a reason for using `apply`.

one more thing to point out is, [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) takes in a function that does something on each column/row, but it seems you were trying to use the function arg as a DataFrame.

Comment: Thx so much or taking the time to answer! It's people like you that make SO such a great place!

Comment: @jimbasquiat glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to inform Pandas that the column should be interpreted as a `Datetime`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(10)))
def test(x):
    x['date'] = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01')
    return x

a = a.apply(test, axis=1)
a.date = a.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

This gives:

```
    0   date
0   0   2017-01-01
1   1   2017-01-01
2   2   2017-01-01
3   3   2017-01-01
4   4   2017-01-01
5   5   2017-01-01
6   6   2017-01-01
7   7   2017-01-01
8   8   2017-01-01
9   9   2017-01-01
```

Alternatively, I was able to do this by creating the column first and setting its type:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data=list(range(10)))
a['date'] = None
a.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')

def test(x):
    x['date'] = pd.Timestamp('2017-01-01')
    return x

a = a.apply(test, axis=1)
```